# How to retrieve aggregated values from a linq query?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following query:

```
from spl in SpeciesLists 
         join ar in Areas on spl.Station.Area equals ar.Id 
         join ground  in Grounds on ar.Ground equals ground.Id 
         join re in Regions on ground.Region  equals re.Id 
         where spl.Station.Trip.year ==2013
         select new 
           {
              SpciesCommonName = slp.Description,
              Are = ar.description,
              Ground = ground.Code,
              NumberOfTripsInProtectedAreas = "To be calculated",
           }
```

A "trip" can include one or more stations. The protected area field is found on the Trip table and can be 1 or 0. A station has one or more species.

How can I calculate the number of trips in protected areas?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Your select list contains "slp.Description", which means your result will contain species list not Trips list! If you want to aggregate for trips, I believe your results should be different. Would you please clarify this?

Comment: Correct, but this is because i need to group the result by the selected columsn. I know this was omitted in the psot.

Comment: So, you want the aggregated value to be on the three columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the condition of ProtectedArea  == 1 in your where clause.

Also as stated in your comments, the group will be by:  slp.Description, ar.description and 
ground.Code

Here is the code:

```
from spl in SpeciesLists 
             join ar in Areas on spl.Station.Area equals ar.Id 
             join ground  in Grounds on ar.Ground equals ground.Id 
             join re in Regions on ground.Region  equals re.Id 
             where spl.Station.Trip.year ==2013
             && spl.Station.Trip.ProtectedArea == 1
             group spl by new { slp.Description, ar.description, ground.Code } into Result
             select new 
               {
                  SpciesCommonName = Result.Key.Description,
                  Are = Result.Key.description,
                  Ground = Result.Key.Code,
                  NumberOfTripsInProtectedAreas = Result.Count()
               }
```

Comment: Hi Adel, This looks extremely elegant. I will implement it and let you know if that solved my problem. many thanks for the effort.